# MATLAB: Identify maxima and minima and split data accordingly

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have the following arrays:

```
x = [1:33]; 
y = [0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0];
```

I need to separate y into different sections. I need to obtain the ascending parts, the descending parts, and the combined ascending and descending parts.

For example:

```
 Ascending parts = [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]; 

 Descending parts = [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
 1 1 1 1 0 0  1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]; 

 Combined parts = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4];
```

I can, of course, do this manually for these arrays, but I need to do this for arrays with hundreds of thousands of points and I wish to do it automatically. I have been playing around with the `findpeaks` functions but this isn't straightforward as it sometimes picks up peaks during the descending/ascending parts, rather than at the end points.

Any tips on how I can do this?

version MATLAB 2017/b

Comment: A hint, try `y(1:end-1)-y(2:end) > 0`

Comment: You should define `combined`.

Comment: The combined part has to include the descending and ascending parts together. See above, for combined part 1 it includes the first ascending and descending parts. Combined part 2 includes the next ascending and descending parts and so on..

Comment: So a combined sequence is an increasing sequence followed by a decreasing sequence of any length?

Comment: exactly! the hint by hesam_EE works well to devide the parts, I just have to think of a way to isolate the seperate ones and zeros, and get the seperate combined parts.

Comment: What if we have two or more consecutive equal elements?

Comment: I am trying to get a structure where I can individually select a descending part, or a ascending part, or the ascending and descending together. For example: structure(combined_part_number).ascending = .., structure(combined_part_number).descending = .., structure(combined_part_number).combined = ..,

Comment: @rahnema1 there are parts of the y array with a number of consecutive elements that are more or less equal to zero but not exactly the same number. I may need a logical removing y values < 0.5 or something.

Comment: @rahnema1 Ascending = [1 1 1 1 1 0 0], Descending = [0 0 0 0 0 1 1], Combined = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1]. Either the ascending or descending parts can include the max number (3 in this example), but not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a problem like this, you should consider using Matlab's `diff`.

For `y = [0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0];`

```
a=diff(y)
1   1   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  1   1   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  1   1   -1  -1  1   1   1   1   -1  -1  -1  -1

b=a, c =a;
b(b<0)=0;
c(c>0)=0;
```

Will give you:

```
b = 1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0

c = 0   0   0   0   0   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  0   0   0   0   0   -1  -1  -1  -1  -1  0   0   -1  -1  0   0   0   0   -1  -1  -1  -1
```

For the second part, you can do the following:

```
z=diff(y, 2);
zd=[0 find(z~=0);0 z(find(z~=0))]

0     5    10    15    20    22    24    28    32
0    -2     2    -2     2    -2     2    -2     2
```

Assuming that this is how your function looks like in general, the above pattern shows convex and concave regions in the sequence. With this assumption, the following should work in your case:

```
za=[0 zd(1,zd(2,:)>0)];
zad=diff(za);
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x,y) repelem(x,y), 1:length(zad),zad,'UniformOutput',false))

ans: 1  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
```

which I believe is close to what you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for this! this is great for separating the data into ascending and descending parts. How would I go about isolating these parts? and obtaining single combined parts?  for example: d(1).b = [1 1 1 1], d(1).c = [-1 -1 -1 -1], d(1).d = [1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1]. But corresponding to values in y rather than diff..

Comment: maybe I can use 'find' and I will see shifts in 'find' index values to seperate the parts?

Comment: For the second part you can do `diff(y,2)` which will give you `0 0 0 0 -2 0 0 0 0 2 ...`. Then you need to identify a negative number (a valley) followed by a positive number (a peak) or a peak followed by the valley.

Comment: @PaysdeGalles, please see the edit and let me know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Yes this pretty much works, thanks for taking time to answer my question. Although it is not exactly what I need so I am currently doing modifications. It misses out the first increasing part but I should be able to change it.

Comment: @PaysdeGalles, glad it helped! Hopefully, it will help you come up with the best solution for the problem at hand, cheers!